# Pandas dataframe: how to plot candlesticks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have following data in dataframe to plot candlesticks.

```
     open   high    close   low
date                
2013-10-08  3.21    3.28    3.27    3.20
2013-10-09  3.25    3.28    3.26    3.22
2013-10-10  3.26    3.27    3.23    3.21
2013-10-11  3.25    3.28    3.27    3.23
2013-10-14  3.28    3.35    3.31    3.26
```

I tried to use candlestick_ohlc function from matplotlib.finance, but it seems that somehow I needed to change the data type of the index 'date'. I am new to python, still trying to figure out a way.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the type of the index? (`df.index.dtype`)

Answer (score 0):

If the index is not a `datetime` (use `df.index.dtype` to find out which type it is), you can change the type to a datetime by using:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

(assuming your dataframe is called `df`)